# Can medial /t/ and /d/ before syllabic /n/ be distinguished easily?

Tags: phonetics, american-english, glottal-stop, syllabic-consonants

**Addendum** (0:00am, June 27th, JST): After reading Draconis' answer, I did a little more research and added my findings below the horizontal line.

Can medial /t/ and /d/ before syllabic /n/ be easily distinguished? Here is an excerpt from p. 84 from [Marianne Celce-Murcia, et. al., "*Teaching Pronunciation*," 2nd ed., Cambridge University Press, 2010](http://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/teacher-training-development-and-research/teaching-pronunciation-2nd-edition).

> ... a consonant sound often anticipates some following sound. Both /t/ (in words like *but͟t͟on* and *kit͟t͟en*) and /d/ (in words like *sud͟d͟en* and *had͟n't*) exhibit unusual medial variants before syllabic [n̩]. The /t/ is either glottalized (articulated with a momentary blockage of the airstream in the vocal cords) or it is replaced by a ***glottal stop*** [ʔ], which is a sound formed when the vocal cords close tightly so that air cannot pass between them. When the consonant /t/ and /d/ is produced before syllabic [n̩], the air used to produce the stop is released through the nose rather than the mouth. Because of these articulatory differences, words with medial /t/ and /d/ before syllabic [n̩] are clearly distinguishable, for example, *sud͟d͟en* versus *Sut͟t͟on*, *bid͟d͟en* versus *bit͟t͟en*.

I am not clear on "these articulatory differences." I guess one interpretation would be that while the medial /t/ before [n̩] has either glottal reinforcement (pre-glottalization) or glottal replacement (borrowing terms from [*Wikipedia*'s entry on "*T-Glottalization*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization)), *the /d/ counterpart does not*, and that is the difference. The part about the /d/ is only implied, not explicitly stated.

Is this correct, though? No glottalization occurs to the medial /d/ before [n̩]? When I look up [the pronunciation of *bitten* in American English on Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/bitten/en_usa/) and compare that with [that of *bidden* there](https://forvo.com/search/bidden/en_usa/), they sound quite similar and the only noticeable difference, at least to me, is the length of the preceding vowel. And even that may be a meaningless observation because these two were clearly spoken by different people. (I know [Forvo](http://forvo.com) is not the most reliable resource, but it is the only readily available one for me at this time.)

They also speak of post-nasalization ([*Wikipedia*'s entry on "*Stop Consonant*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant#Nasalization)), but that is supposed to be a common phenomenon to both /t/ and /d/, so it cannot be a differentiating feature.

I would appreciate it if you could shed some light on this matter. I am not a linguist, still less a phonologist or a phonetician. I teach English (American English, to be specific) and I am trying to educate myself with English phonology/phonetics just so I can be certain of what I teach to my students. One big problem for me is that I do not have innate knowledge of correct pronunciation because I am not a native speaker. Your help would be much appreciated because I honestly do not know whom else to turn to.

---

Even after reading Draconis' answer, I was not convinced that *bidden* is read [bɪɾn̩] --- I was fairly sure at least it is not always. [Pronuncian.com's podcast episode "*66: Syllabic n's and nasal plosions (as in the words 'sudden' and 'couldn't')*"](https://pronuncian.com/podcasts/episode66) deals with this issue head on, and the author says *bidden* many times in this episode, and she realizes the /d/ as [ɾ] only once, at about 2'30" mark.

The rest of the time, she realizes it as [d̚] (no audible release). You could say it is actually [dⁿ] (nasal plosion/release), but I personally do not think adding yet another allophone is helpful, as far as American English is concerned. [*Wikipedia* states to the same effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_release).

So in General American, *bitten* is read either [bɪʔn̩] or [bɪʔt̚n̩] while *bidden*, [bɪd̚n̩]. Since [t̚] = [d̚], I would say they sound quite similar; to my ears, they definitely do. Wouldn't you agree? I guess whether you can differentiate them or not depends on if you can tell [ʔ] from [d̚] (plus possibly the sensitivity to the duration of the preceding vowel). I have zero confidence in my ability to do that, but how about you? Please let me know, because I would really like to know!

Answer (score 4):

In most dialects of American English, medial `/t/` and `/d/` are indistinguishable in most environments: both are realized as `[ɾ]`.

Before a syllabic `/n̩/`, however, they remain distinct: `/t/` becomes glottalized to some extent, while `/d/` never does. For me, the glottalization is complete, and I realize "bitten" as `[bɪʔn̩]` (versus "bidden" `[bɪɾn̩]`). For others, it's more like `[tˀ]`.

Note that this doesn't happen before any other vowel, including other syllabic resonants: "bottom" and "bottle" both have `[ɾ]`. Only before `/n̩/`—which shares `/t/`'s place of articulation, prompting a sort of dissimilation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So indeed no glottalization to /d/... this means I have been pronouncing the /d/ wrong _the whole time_!!! I have thought _pardon_ and _Parton_ (as in Dolly Parton) could be pronounced exactly the same way...

How would you feel if someone (like myself) said [bɪʔn̩] for _bidden_? Would you feel it is categorically wrong, or accept it as a kind of variant?

What do you think of [the pronunciation of _bidden_ on Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/bidden/en_usa/)? I cannot hear a flap/tap --- do you?

Comment: @Yasuro [bɪʔn̩] for bidden, or [pɑɹʔn̩] for pardon, would be understood but not acceptable in General American. As Draconis says, the /d/ is never glottalized in those environments.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: @Draconis, In old English n and ŋ were allophones of the same phoneme. I know that  n → [ŋ]/ _____ k,g. Is there a way to write this rule using features?

Comment: @User384789 This doesn't seem to have any relation to the question or answer here; I'd suggest asking it as a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your additional question, it is when /ən/ is realized as [ən] as opposed to [n̩] that /d/ in *bidden* etc. can be flapped (i.e. realized as [ɾ]). Which isn't common as far as North American English is concerned but it does happen. [d̚n̩] is certainly the predominant pronunciation of /Vdən/ words.

Comment: Thanks. I feel vindicated. :) So let me ask you this --- how confident do you feel about differentiating [bɪʔn̩] and [bɪd̚n̩]?

Comment: You mean in perception? Probably not much, so pronouncing postvocalic /dən/ as [ʔn̩] isn't likely to cause confusion or come off particularly as non-native.

Comment: Wait, I am a little confused. Also, I should have phrased my question better. My apologies. I wanted to know if you can tell them apart when someone says [bɪʔn̩] or [bɪd̚n̩] to you. I want to know this because Marianne Celce-Murcia, et. al., essentially states it is trivially easy and I do not agree with that assertion.

Comment: That is how I interpreted your question, so the answer stands. So I don't agree with Celce-Murcia et al. either. When /ən/ is realized as [ən] rather than [n̩], which is increasingly common in British English, the difference is indeed quite clear: Listen, for example, to the samples of [*bitten*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bitten) and [*hidden*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hidden) by Oxford.

Comment: On Lexico, they pronounce [*bitten*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bitten) and [*hidden*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hidden) with [ən], but [*kitten*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/kitten) and [*bidden*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bidden) with [n̩]. Don't you find the latter pair harder to distinguish?

Comment: YES, I DO! I have been saying _bitten_ and _bidden_ pretty much the same way, so I was taken quite aback when I read that passage in _Teaching Pronunciation_ that I quoted in my original post. I have never been trained in linguistics and I barely have passing knowledge of phonetics. I am not connected any reliable linguists so this venue is pretty much the only place where I can solicit professional opinion. So I value it and appreciate your input very much.